# Current Opportunity details are not coming in Email using apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, email-template

I have created a Apex trigger on opportunity when the **available__C** checkbox unchecked then mail needs to go to opportunity Owners manager..
I have written below trigger.Here mail is getting sent but no opp details are coming in mail..I have used Text template with merge field(like opp.name) which are correct

```
    trigger OnOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert,after update) { 
    set<id>oppId=new set<id>(); 
    map<id,opportunity> OppMap=new map<id,opportunity>(); 
    list<id> userid=new list<id>(); 
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
    if (trigger.isinsert && trigger.isAfter){ 
        for(opportunity opp:trigger.new){ 
            oppmap.put(opp.OwnerId,opp);  
        }
    }
    if (trigger.isupdate && trigger.isAfter){ 
        for(opportunity opp:trigger.new){ 
            if(opp.Avialable__c==false && opp.Avialable__c!=trigger.oldmap.get(opp.id).Avialable__c){
                oppmap.put(opp.OwnerId,opp); 
            } 
        } 
    }     
    Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select id,manager.email,managerid from user where id in:oppmap.keySet()]);
    for (opportunity opp:trigger.new){ 
        if(userMap.containsKey(opp.ownerid)){ 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            mail.setTargetObjectId(userMap.get(opp.ownerid).managerid); 
            mail.setTemplateId('00X28000001Fiuv');     
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [setWhatId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId) method pass Opportunity Id.

```
List<contact> conList = [select id from contact limit 1];

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    mail.setTargetObjectId(conList[0].Id); 
    mail.setToAddresses(new List<string>{userMap.get(opp.ownerid).manager.email}); 
    mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
    mail.setTemplateId('00X28000001Fiuv'); 
    mail.setWhatid(Opp.Id);    
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
```

It will populate the values.

I am passing contact Id because we are using email template.

Comment: Thanks.I added this in code but getting below error     ----"Error:Apex trigger OnOpportunity caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: OnOpportunity: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [whatId, 0062800000BrhcV]: Trigger.OnOpportunity: line 37, column 1   "

Comment: @ajaybagdad check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks tushar. Its working..One more thing .do you suggest any changes in above code for best practices ,as i am new to coding.

Comment: @ajaybagdad one point use trigger handler class to write logic. Other its nice.

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated. thanks very much.